# Unable to load Sentihood dataset Json file in Python

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, nlp, sentiment-analysis

Sentihood Dataset is a dataset for Target Aspect-based Sentiment Analysis. Its Test and Train file are available in Json format. However, when I try loading it using the json module of python, it gives the following error-

JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 7 column 1 (char 6)

Is there some other way of loading Json files? I don't have much knowledge of Json and hence would appreciate any help.
Link for Sentihood dataset : https://github.com/uclmr/jack/tree/master/data/sentihood

My code is simply:

```
with open("sentihood-train.json", "r") as read_it: 
    data = json.load(read_it)
```

Comment: Are you sure you downloaded the file correctly and `sentihood-train.json` is the exact same file as in the github repo? It should be around 1MB large.

Comment: Checked both the train and test json both are working in my case.

Answer (score 0):

When file is reading json.loads needs file content which can be done by following way. Pass `f.read()` in json.loads line.

```py
import json
with open("test.json",mode='r') as f:
    d = json.loads(f.read())  # changed this line
    print(d)
```

Comment: that's basically the same code as @Dornish is using.